# ¿Cómo animar el atributo "d" de la etiqueta "path" de SVG / HTML5?

Tags: html, html5, rutas, svg

Tengo una figura dibujada con la etiqueta Path de **SVG/HTML**. Lo que quiero es que esta figura se genere paso por paso. Es decir que se vea el efecto de animación línea por línea, como si estuviera dibujando a mano alzada. El siguiente es mi código que no funciona:

```html
<svg width="500" height="250">
  <path d="0" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="none">
    <animate attributeName="d" values="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" dur="3s"/>
   </path>
</svg>
```

Estoy intentando animar el atributo `d` de la etiqueta `path`. Cuando animo cualquier otra propiedad funciona, pero con la propiedad "d" algo estoy haciendo mal, y no sé qué es.

Answer (score 4):

### Opción 1: Animando el atributo [`SVG - d`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d)

Para conseguir una animación de dibujo progresivo, una manera es hacerlo de forma "escalonada", es decir, primero indicamos el punto de origen con todos sus futuros puntos de inflexión. Luego usando `animate` vamos moviendo uno a uno dichos puntos

#### Ejemplo:

```html
<svg width="500" height="250">
  <path class="path" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="none" d="M 150,0 l 0,0 l 0,0 l 0,0">
    <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="d" to="M 150,0 L 75,200 l 0,0 l 0,0" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
    <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="d" to="M 150,0 L 75,200 L 225,200 l 0,0" begin="1s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
    <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="d" to="M 150,0 L 75,200 L 225,200 L 150,0" begin="2s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
  </path>
</svg>
```

#### Ejemplo 2:

Otra forma sería usando `values`, como lo indica @enxaneta

```html
<svg width="500" height="250">
  <path class="path" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="none">
    <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="d" values="M 150,0 l 0,0 l 0,0 l 0,0; M 150,0 L 75,200 l 0,0 l 0,0; M 150,0 L 75,200 L 225,200 l 0,0; M 150,0 L 75,200 L 225,200 L 150,0" dur="3s" fill="freeze" />
  </path>
</svg>
```

---

### Opción 2: Usando otros [`SVG - Attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute#Core%20attributes)

Otra forma de lograrlo usando:

- [`stroke-dasharray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray)
- [`stroke-dashoffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dashoffset)

Para que funcione correctamente necesitamos saber el largo total de la línea, el cual podemos obtener usando `Javascript`

```
var path = document.querySelector('.path');
var length = path.getTotalLength();
```

Con ese dato, podemos definir `stroke-dasharray` (*longitud de guiones*) y `stroke-dashoffset` (*espacio entre los guiones*) igual a dicha longitud.
Luego usando `animate` llevamos `stroke-dashoffset` a cero para generar la animación

#### Ejemplo:

```html
<svg width="500" height="250">
  <path class="path" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="577.200" stroke-dashoffset="577.200" fill="none" d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z">
    <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" to="0" dur="3s" fill="freeze" />
  </path>
</svg>
```

---

### Opción 3: Usando `CSS`

También se puede hacerlo con:

- [`animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/animation)

#### Ejemplo:

```css
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 577.200;
  stroke-dashoffset: 577.200;
  animation: line 3s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes line {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="250">
  <path class="path" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="none" d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: También se puede lograr usando `Javascript`, pero como el tag no está en la pregunta lo voy a omitir. En lo personal me inclino por la opción 2, siendo desde mi punto de vista la más simple (_siempre y cuando no se modifique el tamaño del `SVG`_)

Comment: En lugar de utilizar 3 elementos `<animate>` en el primer ejemplo puedes utilizar un solo elemento si en lugar del atributo `to` utilizas el atributo `values`. En este case el valor del atributo `values` sería la lista de valores separados por `;`

Comment: @enxaneta, excelente idea. Actualice mi respuesta (_dandote el crédito_) Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Mmmmmm bueno lo que se me ocurre es que puedas realizarlo con `keyframes` en **CSS** aqui te dejo un ejemplo:

```
<svg width="300px" height="175px" version="1.1">
    <path fill="transparent" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" d="M10 80 Q 77.5 10, 145 80 T 280 80" class="path"></path>
</svg>
```

y en el caso del css seria lo siguiente:

```
svg {
    width: 300px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
svg .path {
    stroke-dasharray: 320;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    animation: dibujar-linea 1s linear;
}
@keyframes dibujar-linea {
    from {
        stroke-dashoffset: 320;
    }
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```

En éste caso se dibuja una linea curva, `stroke-dashoffset` es el que se va modificando en la animación.

Espero te sirva ;) Saludos